# Ionic 3 - how to deselect a tab on leaving the page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am unable to find any proper resource and I have tried multiple items including the following code:

```
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('xxxxx')
```

How do I deselect a tab on leaving the page?

Comment: What do you mean by deselecting? Go to another tab? leave the tabs and open a page without tabs?

Comment: Can you post your actual requirement with your code?